# synchronising MS DB and CouchDB, CouchDB and PouchDb in C#

Tags: c#, couchdb, pouchdb, synchronization

I have got a MS DB with some data about some customers and I want to develop an application which can run offline, therefor I read that CouchDB and PouchDB can sync to each other

How can I synchronise the data from a MS DB to a CouchDB, what's the best way I can implement this.

Furthermore I want to develop this application with C#, is this the best way or should I use JavaScript when I use PouchDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a standard mechanism for synchronizing data between a relational database and CouchDB/PouchDB. This is much dependent of your logic and how you want to map your relational data model to the document oriented data model that is supported by CouchDB/PouchDB.

I recommend you to perform a synchronization between your "MS DB" and a CouchDB as your server side elements.

In the client, you should select a CouchDB client that supports synchronization and is compatible with your selected programing language. PouchDB is a good option if your want to write your application in JavaScript, but if your preferred language is C#, I'll recommend you to have a look to Couchbase Lite for .Net (https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.5/installation/net/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to use CouchDB within .NET context, you should take a look at the [MyCouch Library](https://github.com/danielwertheim/mycouch).

Comment: please explain a little, so that the answer doesn't solely rely on the link to be complete.